# (Responsive Website) UL > LI's min-height:100% while display:inline & vertical-align:top

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive website currently in development for a family member.
I have a small issue...

I have created a generic thumbnail UL with the following extremely striped down code;

**Edit**

(I added to it so people understood more of the process of borders, and drop shadow
I also added the process of connecting to the database and a few other parts for anyone else that my find it useful, its just testing script)

**End of Edit**

```
<?php

include "./Youre/MySQL/Password/File.php";

$noimage = "http://www.howtovanish.com/images/bag.jpg";

$mysqli = new mysqli("$host","$user","$password","$database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE Page = 'Who'";

?>

<section id="sectionGamma" class="clearfix">

    <!-- Start of ulFrame -->
    <ul class="ulFrame fader">

        <li class="liFrame clearfix">

            <div class="divGenericThumbnailList clearfix">

                <ul class="clearfix">

                    <?php

                            $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                            /* associative and numeric array */
                            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
                            {

                                if($row["Section"] == "sectionGamma")
                                {
                                  ?>

                                        <li>

                                        <?php
                                        $i++;
                                        if ($i % 2 == 0) 
                                        {
                                           $img = "imgLeft";
                                           $marg = "margLeftSmall";

                                        }
                                        else 
                                        { 
                                            $img = "imgLeft"; 
                                            $marg = "margRightSmall";

                                        }
                                        ?>

                                        <div class="<?php echo $marg; ?> shadow">
                                        <div class="<?php echo $img; ?> border">
                                            <img src="<?php if($row["Preview"] != NULL){echo "./Image/File/Path/".$row["Preview"];}else{echo $noimage;} ?>" alt=""/>
                                        </div>

                                        <?php echo Markdown($row["Content"]); ?>

                                        </div>

                                 </li>
                                  <?php
                               }

                            }

                        ?>

                </ul>

            </div> 

        </li> 

    </ul>

</section>
```

Each `LI` is output with `php` from a database. I've stripped out 99% of the `php` and just left the part I'm having an issue with.

The CSS for the above code is as follows;

```
.divGenericThumbnailList ul 
{
    display:block;
    min-height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    right: 0;
    left:0;
    font-size: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.divGenericThumbnailList ul li 
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    min-height: 200px;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.divGenericThumbnailList ul li div 
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(211, 214, 219);
}
```

Using the previously mentioned HTML & CSS I get the following result at a width of 478px;

[image: incorrectly displayed LI]

The result I'm trying to achieve is as follows;

[image]

What the page displays like at a screen resolution of 1280px width;

[image]

What the screen looks like at a screen resolution of 320px width;

[image]

The CSS for the margins, border and drop shadow are as follows;

```
/* #################### */
/* Margin  */
/* #################### */

.margLeftSmall
{
     margin-left:2.5px;
}

.margRightSmall
{
   margin-right:2.5px;
}

/* #################### */
/* Shadow  */
/* #################### */

.shadow
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.4px 0.1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.4px 0.1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/* #################### */
/* Border   */
/* #################### */

.border
{
    border: 1px solid rgb(211, 214, 219);
}

/* #################### */
/* Frame */
/* #################### */

.ulFrame
{
border:none;
display:block;
/*border:solid thin yellow;*/
position:relative;
margin:auto;
}

.ulFrame li
{
/*background:green;*/
top:0;
vertical-align:top;
}

.liFrame
{
/*background:#F0F;*/
width:100%;
height:auto;
}

.liFrame p
{
line-height: 25px;
}
```

Does anyone know of a pure `CSS` solution to achieve a responsive `UL`> `LI` that displays `LI`s that are re-sizable but have a min-height of 100%? I would like each `LI` to resize if another `LI` on the same row is resized.

No `Javascrpt`, no `jQuery`...pure `CSS`

I've tried some of the following methods to achieve my goal...as well as a lot more...

1. `min-height:100%;`
2. Reset the layout to a `TABLE` with `TR`
3. Changing the `UL` and `LI` to `display:table;` & `display:table-cell;`
4. Ive been fiddling with separate test layouts.
5. Ive been JSFiddling which can be located at the following location;

[Latest JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9dbd/25/)

[image]

I've basically been troubleshooting this issue for a while.

I understand there are Javascript ways to get around my issue...but I don't want to use Javascript, if scripts are disabled in a users browser then this functionality will be useless...so `CSS` is my only choice.

**Edit**

Think of a div that holds a UL...the div that holds the UL is dynamic in height...it gets its height from its content...the UL inside the div is dynamic in height...it also gets its height from its content...each LI inside the UL are dynamic in height...each LI is 50% of its parent UL so you get 2 LI on each row when displayed inline-block with vertical-align:top...currently the LI get their height from their content, I want to keep this functionality while adding one simple extra, the ability of each LI to have a min-height of 100% so each LI on each row are always the same height...

[image]

**Core of the problem**

Stripped to its core the frame Im having a problem with is as follows;

```
<div class="Parent"><!-- display block & min-height 100% expand to content -->
   <ul class="Child"><!-- display block & min-height 100% expand to content -->

       <!-- Inline list items 50% width 2 per line each list item filling -->
       <!-- the height of the row -->

       <!-- Parent Child GrandChildren -->

       <li></li><!-- ROW 1 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <li></li><!-- ROW 1 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <li></li><!-- ROW 2 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <li></li><!-- ROW 2 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <li></li><!-- ROW 3 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <li></li><!-- ROW 3 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <li></li><!-- ROW 4 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <li></li><!-- ROW 4 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->

   </ul>

</div>
```

Another layout Ive tried is as follows and can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J9dbd/23/);

```
<div class="Parent"><!-- display block & min-height 100% expand to content -->
   <div class="Child"><!-- display block & min-height 100% expand to content -->

       <!-- Inline divs 50% width 2 per line each div filling -->
       <!-- the height of the row -->

       <!-- Parent Child GrandChildren -->

       <div></div><!-- ROW 1 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <div></div><!-- ROW 1 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <div></div><!-- ROW 2 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <div></div><!-- ROW 2 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <div></div><!-- ROW 3 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <div></div><!-- ROW 3 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <div></div><!-- ROW 4 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->
       <div></div><!-- ROW 4 display block min-height 100% expand to content -->

   </div>

</div>
```

A frame Im currently experimenting with you will find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/daq6v/);

```
<table class="Parent"><!-- display block & min-height 100% expand to content -->

<tr class="Child"><!-- ROW 1 display block expand to content -->
    <!-- Parent Child GrandChildren -->
    <td><div></div></td><!-- 50% width expand height to content -->
    <td><div></div></td><!-- 50% width expand height to content -->
</tr>

<tr class="Child"><!-- ROW 2 display block expand to content -->
    <!-- Parent Child GrandChildren -->
    <td><div></div></td><!-- 50% width expand height to content -->
    <td><div></div></td><!-- 50% width expand height to content -->
</tr>

<tr class="Child"><!-- ROW 3 display block expand to content -->
    <!-- Parent Child GrandChildren -->
    <td><div></div></td><!-- 50% width expand height to content -->
    <td><div></div></td><!-- 50% width expand height to content -->
</tr>

<tr class="Child"><!-- ROW 4 display block expand to content -->
    <!-- Parent Child GrandChildren -->
    <td><div></div></td><!-- 50% width expand height to content -->
    <td><div></div></td><!-- 50% width expand height to content -->
</tr>

</table>
```

Another option Im experimenting with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PTjK5/) which involves columns is as follows;

```
<div class="Container">

    <div><img style="height:250px; background:red;" /></div>
    <div><img style="height:200px; background:white;" /></div>
    <div><img style="height:350px; background:blue;" /></div>
    <div><img style="height:450px; background:red;" /></div>
    <div><img style="height:150px; background:yellow;" /></div>
    <div><img style="height:50px;  background:green;" /></div>

</div>
```

The CSS for the columns

```
.Container
{
    column-count:2;
    -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.Container div img
{
   display:block;
   min-height: 250px;
   border:solid thin black;
}
```

What Im trying to achieve;

[image]

**JQuery Fix**

This is an example using JQuery similar to what Im aiming to achieve - [Equal Height Blocks in Rows](http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/)

Stephen Akins JQuery solution can be found [here](http://stephenakins.blogspot.com/2011/01/uniform-div-heights-for-liquid-css-p.html)

As you can see from the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rYb4/3/) I can nearly accomplish my goal using Stephen Akins JQuery fix...

1. The container does not resize to the content...
2. If scripts are disabled in the browser then the functionality is lost...

**Working JQuery Example**

A working JQuery version can be found [here](http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc)

**What Im looking for with CSS instead of the current JQuery**

A semi working version of what I'm looking for is located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4rYb4/5/) just need to make sure the heights work once the body has loaded...

Comment: Heres a JSFiddle that Ive also been playing with... http://jsfiddle.net/J9dbd/ it simply shows you the problem I am having...no fix as yet sorry...

Comment: So you want equal height `div`s?

Comment: Yes equal height LI's or div's...Ive tried a div solution but Im still getting the same issue...as long as the divs are adjustable to the content held within while maintaining a 100% height if the content isnt long enough to fill the div...or LI

Comment: The 1st parent containing div needs to adjust to the children...and each child adjusts to its content... .divGenericThumbnailList ul li needs to be adjustable to its contents if the content overflows but if not then .divGenericThumbnailList ul li needs to be 100% height...

Comment: If you want borders around your `<div>`, I think this can only be done with JavaScript or CSS3 flexboxes.

Comment: Ive updated the code with some parts of how the border and shadow are done...as well as how data is recovered from the database so you can see more of the process...

Comment: The box-lines property is not supported in any of the major browsers. (box-lines:multiple;) Source: [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-lines.asp) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6CpH/2/)

Comment: @nwellnhof Flex Browser Support is not very good so accessibility will be poor [here](https://cdn.anonfiles.com/1390148603449.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got you now. I finally understand your question. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9dbd/41/) that does exactly what you want it to. Hope this helps.

Here's the Jquery also:

```
var count = $('.container > div').length;
var height = 0;

for (var i = 1;i<=count;i++)
{
    if ($('.container > div:nth-child('+i+')').height() > height)
    {
        height = $('.container > div:nth-child('+i+')').height();
    }
}

$('.container > div').css('min-height', height);
```

Note: This finds the div (or li a you would apply it) with the biggest height value and sets all the divs that are on it's level to the same min-height. You can easily adjust this to only set the div that's adjacent to it to the same min-height.

Comment: No...nothing to do with bottom borders...someone asked me about borders thats why borders are mentioned...

Comment: Think of a div that holds a UL...the div that holds the UL is dynamic in height...it gets its height from its content...the UL inside the div is dynamic in height...it also gets its height from its content...each LI inside the UL are dynamic in height...each LI is 50% of its parent UL so you get 2 LI on each row when displayed inline-block with vertical-align:top...currently the LI get their height from their content, I want to keep this functionality while adding one simple extra, the ability of each LI to have a min-height of 100% so each LI on each row are always the same height...

Comment: Here is the [Latest JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9dbd/22/) Ive been working on, you will see it has nothing to do with borders, I can get borders to work ok, its the LIs need to 1. Get their height from their content 2. While maintaining 1 they need to have a height of 100% of their row if the content isnt that much as to push the LI down to fill its parent container

Comment: Your code works properly. It just doens't "look" right. But it's behaving the way you want it to. Take a look at this jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J9dbd/35/ . As you can see, the container divs get the proper height no matter what content goes in there. All I did was add a border-top to each .container div so it simulates alignment.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question but this seems like the easiest fix to me. The tops of the div will always align properly. You can add the border-top to two adjacent divs to make it look like it is the bottom border of the div above them. again, like I said, maybe I'm wrong but this seems like a fix to me

Comment: The LI's don't sit at 100%...I want the LI's to be a minimum of 100% of the row they are on...so say we have 4 LI's at 50% width each...displayed inline and aligned to the top...automatically we would get two rows of LI's...2 on the top and two on the bottom...now say we have 6 LI's at 50% width...we would get 3 rows...and so on and so forth...each LI will adjust to its content...but does not seem to hold a min height of its row...

Comment: so if you want borders to display right, the way html and css work you can't seem to get LI's to display at min-height of 100% which would make sure on each row there is no white space and each LI is symmetrical...

Comment: The lists don't display fully the way I want them to work otherwise I wouldn't be asking my question!!! the list works semi the way I want it in that they have the ability to adjust to their content, but the LI's don't maintain a min-height of 100% of their row...if I use border top of the next row then border left and right still wont display right no the LI, there will be no gap of 5px between the bottom border of one row and the top border of the second row...

Comment: Think of a div inside a LI, the div having a border all the way around...the LI is inside a UL...each LI is at 50% width...each LI's height must A. adjust to its content B. maintain a min-height of 100% of its row...so all LIs will always be the same height which is dynamic to its content...if one LI has less content it will adjust to 100% of its row...

Comment: The div inside the Li with the border, must A. adjust to its content B. maintain a min-height of 100% of its parent if there is not enough data to fill the LI to 100% height...so what we have is a symmetrical UL, with symmetrical LI's...

Comment: The problem Im having is with the LI, it refuses to pull the min-height to 100% of its row...if I can get the LI to pull to 100% of its row then the div within the LI will also pull into place and so on and so forth...the problem is the min-height of the LI within the UL...the problem is the LI inside the UL has a dynamic height of its content which I want, but if the content is not enough as to make the LIs symmetrical then the LI needs to pull to 100% min-height of the row it is on...

Comment: It is achievable because Ive seen it done & done it before, Id saved the script but recently changed my OS due to NSA spying and I didn't back it up...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't be able to achieve this 100% with CSS because continously setting the min-height to 100% is not going to work. If a child has a min-height of 100% nd so does the parent and so on and so forth, there's no actual hard-coded value for them to resort to. Basically, you need an actual pixel or percentage value somewhere along the line so everything else can inherit from there.

Comment: Also, without jQuery, you could simply set the value of min-height of the .container > div to something like 150px and it would work. Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9dbd/42/)